# C# TableEntity keeps IgnoredProperty after Insert Operation

Tags: c#, azure, azure-table-storage

I have the following class that implements TableEntity:

```
public class MyEntity : TableEntity
{
    public string MyProperty { get; set; }

    [IgnoreProperty]
    public string MyIgnoredProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Then I have the following code, that inserts a TableEntity:

```
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("connectionString");
CloudTableClient tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();

ITableEntity entity = new MyEntity ();
entity.RowKey = "row";
entity.PartitionKey = "partition";
entity.MyIgnoredProperty = "ignored";

CloudTable currentTable = tableClient.GetTableReference("MyEntity");
TableOperation insertOrMergeOperation = TableOperation.InsertOrMerge(entity);
TableResult result = await currentTable.ExecuteAsync(insertOrMergeOperation);
var insertedEntity = result.Result as ITableEntity;
```

Now the strange part is that *insertedEntity* contains the MyIgnoredProperty, although I would expect that it shouldn't contain it.

Can someone explain why it behaves like this?.

By the way, If I retrieve the entity explicitly with the following code, the MyIgnoredProperty is not set also not in the DB. As expected.

```
...
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("connectionString");
CloudTableClient tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();

CloudTable currentTable = tableClient.GetTableReference(tableName);
TableOperation retrieveOperation = TableOperation.Retrieve<T>(partitionKey, rowKey);
TableResult tableResult = await currentTable.ExecuteAsync(retrieveOperation);
T result = (T)tableResult.Result;
```

Comment: `Now the strange part is that insertedEntity contains the MyIgnoredProperty, although I would expect that it shouldn't contain it.` - Have you checked in Table Storage if the entity contains this property? My guess is that it is getting initialized to default value when you deserialized the entity.

Comment: In the TableStorage the property is not set. Initializing to default is also what I first thought, but it is not the case, I checked it. It has the same Value as the entity.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe is an issue with ExecuteAsync that it return the same objet as sended , without applying attribute , 
here is a workaround to this , is a script that copy all value of properties excepts one that have specific attributes

```
    public static class Helper
    {
        public static MyEntity copyme(this MyEntity entity)
        {
            var copy = new MyEntity();
            var properties = typeof(MyEntity).GetProperties();

            var propertiesToExcept = typeof(MyEntity).GetProperties()
    .Where(prop => prop.IsDefined(typeof(IgnorePropertyAttribute), false));

            foreach (var prop in properties)
            {
                if (!propertiesToExcept.Any(acc => acc.Name == prop.Name))
                {
                    prop.SetValue(copy, prop.GetValue(entity));
                }
            }
            return copy;


        }
    }
```

and in order to use this simply call

```
                var obj = new MyEntity()
                {
                    MyIgnoredProperty = "toignore",
                    MyProperty = "tokeep"
                };
                var cleanobj = obj.copyme();
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure (as I was not able to find the code for it) but I believe this is being done by the SDK.

I believe what SDK is doing is when you are inserting an entity, at the time of serializing it is creating a JSON payload by removing the properties marked as `IgnoreProperty`. However your `TableEntity` object (`entity` in your case) still has this property.

Once the SDK receives the response, it simply updates the `ETag` and `Timestamp` property of your `entity` and returns that object back in `TableResult.Result`.

Comment: that's also what I guessed